# FCM Notification is not working If i send it by using ARC ( Advanced REST API )

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I integrated the push notification system with Firebase in my project and it's working well except one thing.

If I try to send a notification from Firebase console, using Device Token & Topic, the notification shows in device. 
If I try to send a notification from ARC ( Advance REST CLIENT) using Device Token, the notification shows in device.
If I try to send a notification from ARC ( Advance REST CLIENT) using my topic, NOTHING HAPPENS.

```
Requested URL : https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
RAW headers : 
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: key=AIz.....
RAW PAYLOAD : 
    {
    "data":
    {
    "employeename":"kumaran","empid":"234444"
    },
    "to":"/topics/bmmembers"
    }
Response Header
Status : 200: OK
JSON : 
{
"message_id": 6536474446058224000
}
```

**But my device not received any notification and checked Logcat whether any json arrived in client end, but not received.
Any idea and how we need to resolve this issues.**

Comment: Hi. Do post your code snippet for receiving the message and sample payload for when you're sending using the device token (for comparison). :)

Comment: Are you sure the user/device is subscribed to the topic?

Comment: FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("employee"); i Added this code. Timebeing i subscribed 2 devices and got the notification if i sent it via Firebase console

Comment: Did u try sending the message from firebase consolse? and try sending user specific pnsss.. to debug the issue..

Comment: I got a notification if i send it from firebase console using RegID or Topic. IF i did the same from ARC then REGID only i got it. TOPIC not working

Comment: Read this blogpost on how to send firebase push notification from rest client .http://developine.com/how-to-send-firebase-push-notifications-from-app-server-tutorial/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is my trial and error type of a "Solution found for this Issue":-**

Issue found is "The Quota for the particular Server-key or credential or the whole Google API Account itself might have been expired or used the limit. "
Below i have explained how i once again successfully received FCM Notifiaction with Image for the same Android App.

**ISSUE:-**
I was unable to send FCM push notification (with image) from Advanced REST Client, by using the Android key generated from Google API console in my very old created Project (Eg: My Project; that has 5-apps and its credentials).
I tried sending the Post request from ARC client many time but dint receive any single FCM notification in my Android Mobile.

**SOLUTION I FOUND WAS:-**

1a. I deleted the credentials (API key, server key,web key, OAuth key etc) in Google API console related to that particular app (Eg: FCM App1).

1b. Also i went to Firebase console and deleted the particular app in its project also.
Finally now the App (Eg.FCM App1) doesn't contain connection with 
1.Google API console and with 
2.Firebase Console.

1c. I also deleted the "google-services.json" file from the Android studio->Project folder.(If you are unable to delete this, try executing File->'Invalidate cache and restart' option and then retry deleting it. It will get deleted.)

Next, freshly

1. I created a new gmail account, and opened a new Google API Account, further opened a fresh new Project in that Google API Account (Eg: My Project1).
2. Next, I went to Firebase console signing in with this newly created Gmail acccount, opened a fresh new Project, selected "Add App" and selected "Android".

-> entered my package name, SHA1 key and Added the App.
-> Also downloadedthe new google-services.json file and added again in the Project folder in Android Studio.

-> And followed everything as per previous procedure.

==> Finally I got the fresh ""Server-Key"" in the new Google API console. Copied this server-key and pasted in Advanced REST client at place Authorization:key=AIzaSyAJzs-DDD......etc.

=> added the correct TokenID freshly created for this App from Log.

===> Pressed SEND button in the ARC, and WOOOOWWWW....

within few seconds I GOT THE FCM NOTIFICATION WITH IMAGE IN MY ANDROID MOBILE EVENTHOUGH MY APP WAS IN BACKGROUND OR COMPLETELY CLOSED at that time....!!!

Comment: Actual problem is SERVER KEY. NOW TRIED AND RE-CREATE AGAIN, ITS WORKING WELL. Thanks